# When was the environment variable PS1 created?

Tags: environment-variables, prompt, history

I've always seen reference to pwd as being very essential 'back in the day'. These days we have customized command prompts like PS1 that display the current directory and pwd is pretty outmoded. But when did the idea for ps1 get introduced into *nix systems? Watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc4ROCJYbm0) from the AT&T archives I can see that PS1 definitely did not exist in the seventies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable is part of the shell, `$PS1` is used in `bash`, the Bourne shell (`sh`) and the `ksh`, it is not used in the `csh`.

The first UNIX shell was the Thompson Shell (which was also called `sh` like the later bourne shell, the Thompson Shell was often called `osh` on systems with both the Thompson and Bourne shell installed.) The Thompson shell used the variable `$P` for the prompt.

Then the Bourne Shell was introduced which used `$PS1` to set the prompt. `ksh` was based on the Bourne Shell, and also uses `$PS1`. The `csh`/`tcsh` used `set prompt = <something>`.

So I think the first shell to use `$PS1` was the Bourne Shell.

Thompson Shell man page: https://etsh.io/man/osh.1.pdf

Bourne Shell man page: http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html

Comment: If the Thompson Shell had a variable for the prompt, $P, why did they never customize a prompt to display the working directory?

Comment: You could do if you wanted to, I expect it just wasn't the convention back then. Remember they would have been using 80 character wide terminals where space was a bit more of a luxury.

Comment: So let me add the final answer to **when** did `PS1` first appear. It was 1976 in the Bourne Shell.